# How to move nfs info to kubernetes patch file?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

If I have under volumes

```
name: nfslocation
      nfs:
        server: 10.1.1.3
        path: /vol/vol104/ostntfs0/folder/folder2
```

And I want to move it to a patch file, 
how do I do that?

```
-op: replace
...
```

I am not clear on the format.

Something like

```
-op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/...
```

We use kustomization...

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://kustomize.io/tutorial It will help you to generate proper patch file from the base yaml.

Answer (score 1):

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/4/nfs/server
  value: 10.1.1.3
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/4/nfs/path
  value: /vol/vol104/ostntfs0/folder/folder2
```

This worked out for me...